# Overlay conflict with input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, field, overlay

Had a question. I'm trying to include a widget (which is contained in a div) for my landing page. Now, essentially what I am trying to do is when i hit the button is to fire the OverLayTwo BUT have it fall to the background, instead of the foreground. I tried the z-index method and it doesn't seem to help.

```
    <div class="OverLay">

     <div class="widgetContainer">
      <li>This is a Div</li>
       First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
     </div>

     <div class="OverLayTwo">

     </div>

      <button class="randomButton">Hello</button>

    </div>
```

So essentially what I want is when User hits button, to have 'OverLayTwo' drop however have it fall to the BACKGROUND/backdrop behind the "widgetContainer" div. --

The reason is I want the user to be able to type into the input field(s), however, lately everything I have looked at or referenced is not solving the problem. Essentially just drops the overlay ontop/into the front of the widget - Not allowing the user to enter text into the appropriate input field.

Hope that made sense. The land of CSS is a true maze o.o ...Also, it should be noted I am using javascript and jQuery functionality.

Any tips and/or suggestions would be truly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Show your css/javascript as well.

Comment: `div > li` is not permitted/valid by html5 [standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context) - just sayin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would be hard to make it fall in the background when it lives inside the first overlay.. try something like this..

```
<div class="OverLay" style="z-index:100">
 <div class="widgetContainer">
  <li>This is a Div</li>
   First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
 </div>
  <button class="randomButton">Hello</button>
</div>

<div class="OverLayTwo"  style="z-index:90">
 </div>
```

Comment: Okay, well that worked ! So, that's awesome thank you SO much - now that it's working though, for some reason the colors aren't behaving correctly? One sec, i'll put up the CSS -  Also, curious as to what happened - did you send the first div to the foreground and the second to the background?  o_o

Comment: Oh you just took it out of scope, I get it. - Any idea as to what might be going on with the colors? I will set it 'black' or as written above (with slight transparency) and it returns gray ...

Comment: if you make a jsfiddle to show me what you mean i will take a look.

Comment: Hi Pamblam, here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gh6gzeno/4/  -- conceptually speaking, I'm trying to make it so when user hits "hello" button, '.overLayTwo' fades-In behind '.widgetContainer', and the user still be able to type into the input field.  -- and for some reason the color is showing up gray, when I want it to be black with like a 0.7 or 0.8 opacity.     -- apologies for writing a lot. x:

Comment: transparent black with a white background is grey. think about it :P. i did have a look at your fiddle tho. i've added some notes, see the comments. good luck: https://jsfiddle.net/gh6gzeno/5/

Comment: Hi Pamblam, thank you for the pointers and tips, really helpful.  - so follow up question, is there a way then I can make it so when I do hit that button it appears as black as possible OR atleast as close to a blue as possible? considering it has a white background underneath? xD

Comment: Nevermind - figured it out. Thank you Pamblam and all of you as well. <3